# Importing Excel XLS file into SSIS - converting header row and adding that to underlying records

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel XLS file which we would like to import to a database using SSIS.

The format of the file is as below

This is the Input File

[image: This is the Input File]

I would like to convert it to insert into a SQL table in the following format

SQL table layout

[image: SQL table layout]

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?
I have a second question on the way to split the Investor Name/Address cell into multiple columns, but will put that in a separate question.

Thanks in Advance
Steve

Comment: You would get more help if you didn't use pictures. Not everyone has the ability to see them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried to layout the fields in text, but block or code didnt seem to work.  What would you recommend I use to lay it out

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do a transformation as complex as this is with a script task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on phone now.

Here's what i suggest

Import rows a$5:g

Import excel. 
Conditional split out null accounts.

It seems like all investor account hrs are numbers

Add script component as transform

On output add your 3 columns you want.

Outside row transform add 3 variables to meet your requirement ( ie string adv; et al )

Inside row 
If(!int.tryparse(row.investorid)
{Adv= row.investmentid 
...
}
Else
{
Row.advisor=adv
...
}

Done w script

Add conditional split to ignore null advisors.